# Subsonic 3 query like clause

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

This may be another of those "should be simple" things, but I can't find anything on it so here I am asking what will most likely be a stupid question :$

I'm using SubSonic 3 and I want to execute a query with a like clause but can't find that as an option. My straight SQL is like so:

select * from table where column like %value% or column like %anothervalue%

Thanks for any help.

Jon

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the fluent interface as follows:

```
List<Product> products = new MyDB().Select
            .From(ProductTable)
            .Where(ProductTable.CategoryColumn).Like("%searchstring%")
            .ExecuteTypedList<Product>();
```

Or using Contains:

```
List<Product> products = new MyDB().Select
            .From(ProductTable)
            .Where(ProductTable.CategoryColumn).Contains("searchstring")
            .ExecuteTypedList<Product>();
```

MyDB is your generated DB name

Or using linq:

```
List<Product> products = from p in Product.All()
                         where p.Category.Contains("searchstring")
                         select p;
```

Comment: Thanks for those. The Linq is the one I was looking for. I guess Contains should have been obvious. I kept looking for a where p.Cat like "blah" type syntax. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linq you can use StartsWith(), EndsWith(), and Contains()

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out. I'm still getting used to the syntax of SubSonic3. It's a great tool!